# How do people link twitter handles to e-mail accounts

Tags: social-media

I've seen companies start to advertise that they can link twitter handles to e-mails and vice-a-verse -- this sounds like a bit of a tall claim.

Anybody have any thoughts on how reliable these claims are?

Comment: user1172468@gmail.com ???

Comment: that's what I thought -- but like with your example my e-mail is not user1172468@gmail.com

Comment: Could you please detail how is this an "Open data" question? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending upon a Twitter user's Twitter configuration you can locate their Twitter profile searching with their email address or telephone number. See more here: https://support.twitter.com/articles/20170001.

I'm unaware of a quick way to locate an email address with ONLY a Twitter ID.

I suppose someone with a list of valid email addresses could bang away at Twitter and build their own Db of email addresses to Twitter IDs.

If there is a match on an email I think it would be moderately to very reliable. The absence of a match, however, would very unreliably indicate the absence of a corresponding Twitter profile.